# PHP laravel middleware in boot()

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, service-provider

In my project I am using Laravel 5.2 and now I'm stuck at this little problem I cant figure out how to fix.

I need to share a variable, only with signed users, on all views.
I know I need to use `view() -> composer()` to do this, but how?

Where would the code go? I can't use it in the AppServiceProvider since the `boot()` method is run before the session is started. I have seen someone recomend using middleware to do what I'm trying to do, but I cant figure out that either. 
Where would i write this new middleware? Where would i then use `view() -> composer()`?

A little more detail:
I'm, trying to check for friend requests, and put that in the users sidebar on every view if there are any requests.

And my view composer looks like this in the `boot()` method, but does not work because of `Auth::check()`

```
    if (Auth::check()) {

        view() -> composer('*', function($view) {

            // Check for friend requests
            $friend_requests = DB::table('friends')
                -> where('user_id_receiver', '=', Auth::user() -> id)
                -> where (function($query) {
                    $query -> where('status', '=', 2);
                })
                -> get();

            $view -> with('friend_requests', $friend_requests);

        });

    }
```

My blade layout is also pretty simple, just using extends and includes for sidebar and other stuff.

If I need to clarify something, please tell.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, I actually figured it out.
I created a new provider I called ViewComposerServiceProvider (did this from the artisan command line).

The `boot()` method in the provider now looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{

    view() -> composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\UserMenuComposer');

}
```

Then I created a new folder in App/Http that I called ViewComposers, this is where I now bind variables that I need for some of the views. In this folder, I currently have 1 file now, because that was all I needed for now.

The file is called UserMenuComposer and the content is this:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

    use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class UserMenuComposer {

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view -> with('friendRequests', $this -> getFriendRequests());
    }

    /**
     * Get all friend requests
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getFriendRequests()
    {

        if (Auth::check()) {

            return DB::table('friends')
            -> where('user_id_receiver', '=', Auth::user() -> id)
            -> where (function($query) {
                $query -> where('status', '=', 2);
            })
            -> get();

        } else {

            return false;

        }


    }

}
```

Then lastly, I now can access the Auth() in her as you can see.